# Conditional Statement to build message for PHP Mailer

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a mail.php which takes post data from AJAX.

I have sanitized and assigned Variables.
When composing the PHP Mail Body message. I want to use a conditional statement to evaluate if the forms text fields passed a value. If it evaluates as true then generate the HTML code in the $message so that the form is accurate. At the moment my code only yields the result of the first conditional statement and seems to not evaluate the rest of the conditional statements.

My mail.php code is below:

```
// Required Meeting Request fields
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<center><H1>CDA IT Meeting Request Form</H1></center>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10" width="500px" style="margin:10px auto;">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . $emp_Name . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $emp_Email . "</td></tr>";
if($req_Name != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Requestor's Name:</strong></td><td>" . $req_Name . "</td></tr>";
}
if($req_Email != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Requestor's Email:</strong></td><td>" . $req_Email . "</td></tr>";
}
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Function:</strong> </td><td>" . $meeting_Function . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Setup Date & Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $borrow_Date . " " . $time_Setup ."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Start Date & Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $borrow_Date . " " . $time_Actual ."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Return Date & Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $return_Date . " " . $end_Time ."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Location:</strong> </td><td>" . $Loc ."</td></tr>";
// Conditional entries
if($hw_LcdProjectorQty != "") {
    $message  .= "<tr><td><strong>Projector</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_LcdProjectorQty ."</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_LaptopQty != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Laptop(s)</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_LaptopQty ."</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_WiredMouseQty != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Wired Mouse</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_WiredMouseQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_WiredKeyboardQty != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Wird Keyboard</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_WiredKeyboardQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_iPadQty != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>iPad</strong></td><td>Quantity:" . $hw_iPadQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_RemoteMouseQty != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Remote Mouse</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_RemoteMouseQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_HandMicQty != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Hand Microphone</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_HandMicQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_LapelMicQty != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Lapel Microphone</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_LapelMicQty . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_MediaCart != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Media Cart</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_MediaCart . "</td></tr>";
}

if($hw_PolyComPhone != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Polycom Conference Phone</strong></td><td>Quantity: " . $hw_PolyComPhone . "</td></tr>";
}

if($Applications != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Applications Requested:</strong></td><td>" . $Applications . "</td></tr>";
}

if($Comment != "") {
    $massage  .= "<tr><td><strong>Comments/Special Instructions</strong></td><td>" . $Comment . "</td></tr>";
}

$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Status:</strong> </td><td>Request Submitted</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
```

The $hw_LcdProjectorQty is the only conditional that seems to be firing. The QTY variables only contain a value from 1 through 16.

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump` all the variables?

Comment: where are you getting the $hw variables? param or predefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spot the difference:

```
$message = '<html><body>';
  ^---- letter E

if($hw_LaptopQty != "") {
    $massage  .=
      ^---letter A
```

You have this A v.s. E difference ALL over your code.

Perhaps you've been watching Pink Panther movies too much... "Excuse me, inspector. I have a message for you" "A massage!?"